# Maestro becoming a Sigel Knight - which skills will remain?

Tags: lineage-2

With the new update to Lineage II coming on 2011-11-30 to NCSoft West servers, people who levelled their characters up to level 76 will gain the ability to chose *any* post-awakening class (using the Stone of Destiny item) instead of being stuck with their main class default. This means that - for example - a Maestro can become not only a Tyrr Warrior, but also for example an Othell Rogue or a Sigel Knight.

As a Dwarf. a Maestro has superior (racial-based) CON, and tanks depend on high CON, so this awakening path is a tempting one. The question is however, which Maestro skills will the post-awakening skills of a Sigel Knight overwrite? Or the other way around - which unique skills - like the golem summonings or buffs - will remain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't found the answer already, when you awaken to a class that is not available by default, you get human stats for it.
so if you as a dwarf awaken as a knight, you'll get the stats off a human fighter

as for skills, everything is gone. you won't be able to keep any skills that are not related to the class

source : http://boards.lineage2.com/showthread.php?t=218918